# " value_counts()" and "agg('count')" returning different results

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and one of its columns (named '`income`')  has int values. Some fields have 0 as set value.

When I call

```
print(df[df['income'] == 0].agg('count'))
```

It returns the exact count of 0 values in the DF column.

Occurs that if I call

```
print(df['income'].value_counts()[df['income'].value_counts() == 0])
```

It returns a empty Series:

```
Series([], Name: income, dtype: int64)
```

Can someone please help me deciphering pandas sometimes ilogical behaviour? What's wrong with my second code that pandas does not return the count of 0 values in the dataframe?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select `Series` after [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) by index - here `0` for count of `0` values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'income':[0,5,4,5,0,4,0,5,5],
})


print(df['income'].value_counts())
5    4
0    3
4    2
Name: income, dtype: int64
    
print(df['income'].value_counts().loc[0])
3
```

For get number of rows matching condition is possible get length of `DataFrame`:

```
print(len(df[df['income'] == 0]))
3
```

Or count `True`s by `sum`:

```
print((df['income'] == 0).sum())
3

print(df[df['income'] == 0].agg('count'))
income    3
dtype: int64
```

EDIT: If check by values of `Series` get all values by counts:

```
s = df['income'].value_counts()
print (s)
5    4
0    3
4    2
Name: income, dtype: int64

#number of 3 values
print (s.loc[0])
3

#what values are 4 times?
print (s[s == 4])
5    4
Name: income, dtype: int64

#what values are 2 times?
print (s[s == 2])
4    2
Name: income, dtype: int64

#what values are 0 times?
print (s[s == 0])
Series([], Name: income, dtype: int64)
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, but I would like to understand what is wrong with my second line of code, since I could not find any mistake with the bool passed as filter:  [df['income'].value_counts() == 0]

Comment: @jaymzleutz - There is wrong you want select by counts, so it is like get row if count is `0`, in my sample data try `print(df['income'].value_counts()[df['income'].value_counts() == 4])` - get  `4` - because there is 4 times value `5`

Comment: How would I properly count all the 0 values found, then? Only by my first line of code?

Comment: @jaymzleutz - Like my first solution. `print(df['income'].value_counts().loc[0])`. If check edit I show `print (s[s == 0])` means test values which not exists, (0 times)